# Using Word templates within a library

Tags: document-library

I have created a SP library to house a couple hundred policy and procedure documents for a company.  Some of these documents are Word templates that when opened from explorer open as new documents (as I want them to). When opened from the library they open the original template.  I know I can create content types for each template and be able to list them in the add document button but I want them listed in the library.

In other words, can I get a Word template document to open from a library as a new document or can I show a link in the library to the content types I created for that library?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method is to create content types for each template.

https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-multiple-Office-templates-to-a-document-library-cde94e90-a1ba-4b94-a187-600ed68562bb

[Need Word Template to create new doc (not to checkout, not to edit existing - just create new in MS-Word](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87977/need-word-template-to-create-new-doc-not-to-checkout-not-to-edit-existing-ju)